# Coker of powers of an endomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra, noetherian

Let $F\in\operatorname{End}_R(M)$, where $M$ is a Noetherian $R$-module. If $\operatorname{Coker}F$ is of finite length, is Coker and Ker of all powers of $F$ of finite length? Is the condition of being noetherian necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an exact sequence

$$0 \to \operatorname{Im}(F)/\operatorname{Im}(F^2) \to \operatorname{Coker}(F^2) \to \operatorname{Coker}(F) \to 0,$$

thus it suffices to show that $\operatorname{Im}(F)/\operatorname{Im}(F^2)$ has finite length.

Consider the surjective composition $M \twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{Im}(F) \twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{Im}(F)/\operatorname{Im}(F^2)$. Clearly $\operatorname{Im}(F)$ is contained in the kernel of this map, hence we get a map

$$\operatorname{Coker}(F)=M/\operatorname{Im}(F) \twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{Im}(F)/\operatorname{Im}(F^2),$$

hence the result.

Seems that I have not used the noetherian property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For the case of "Ker" may the noetherian-ness be applied? I could not reach any conclusion.